# ¿Cómo actualizar un documento en MongoDB seleccionándolo con su _id en NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Quiero actualizar un documento en MongoDB seleccionandolo con su _id y no he podido. Cuando lo hago seleccionandolo con otro campo (por ejemplo con el equipo) sí funciona.
Adjunto la petición a MongoDB.

```
 const result = await cliente.db(db)
        .collection(coleccion)
        .updateOne({ _id:"ObjectId('636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd')" }, { $set: {
        equipo : "Bulls"} });

        console.log(result)
}
```

También intenté lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
 const result = await cliente.db(db)
        .collection(coleccion)
        .updateOne({ _id:'636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd'}, { $set: {
        equipo : "Bulls"} });

        console.log(result)
}
```

En la consola me aparece lo siguiente:

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

También intenté de esta forma y no funciona:

```
{_id: ObjectId('636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd'}
```

En este caso en la consola me aparece el siguiente error:

> ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: Según la documentación debe ser: { _id: <value>, <shardkeyfield>: null } entonces usted siga:  updateOne({_id: '636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd'})....

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero ya intenté eso y no funcionó @mafu

Comment: Verifique que la colección sea la correcta y la función asíncrona. Esta actualizando el campo `equipo` a 'Bulls' del documento con _id: '636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd'  ¿Y que error tiene?  @ZCH

Comment: Que error te tira, o que respuesta arroja

Comment: @mafu  Creo que el problema es que no encuentra el documento. Ya agregué lo que me marca la consola. Cuando busco el documento con otro campo como por ejemplo el equipo sí funciona.
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @ZCH intentaste escribir `{_id: ObjectId("636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd"}`. Note como `ObjectId` se encuentra fuera de comilas, tanto simples como dobles, y únicamente llas utilizo en el id

Comment: @EliasParadaLozano intenté hacerlo como sugieres pero me marca el siguiente error: `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el `_id` dentro de la base de datos no es un `string`, es un `ObjectId`, entonces compararlo con `"ObjectId("636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd")"` o compararlo con `"636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd"` no te va a funcionar, porque ambos valores son `string`.

Lo que debes compararlo con un `ObjectId`

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,

const result = await cliente.db(db)
        .collection(coleccion)
        .updateOne({ _id: ObjectID('636b282d8a0d4af32dc295cd')}, { $set: {
        equipo : "Bulls"} });

        console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero no funciona. Intenté lo que sugieres y me manda el siguiente error a la consola: `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`.

Comment: Si incluiste la linea del `require`?

Comment: No, solo hice el require a Mongo: `const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')`

Comment: Por eso te sale que "is not defined", debes definirlo con el `require`

Comment: Qué es lo que tengo que requerir? No es suficiente con el require a mongodb?

Comment: No, con tu `require` solo estás requiriendo el `MongoClient`, pero no el `ObjectID`, puedes copiar y pegar mi línea de código y ponerla en la tuya (no importa que hayan 2 require de mongo). O también puedes cambiar la tuya y dejar una sola así:  `const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb')`